# using this to hold variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why not just use `let total` in below case? I know the purpose is to demo how arrow function solve the `this` dilemma but in the real world do we have real use case for this?

```
function sum() {
  this.total = 0;

  arr.forEach((item) => {
    this.total+= item;  // all is well `this` points to outer function
  })
  return this.total;
}
```

Comment: By `return total;`, do you mean `return this.total;`? Otherwise, it won't work

Comment: If so, I agree with you, that's a really weird example - a function whose only purpose appears to be to return a value, and doesn't take information from its calling context, should not use `this`. It'll even throw an error in strict mode if called without a calling context (and it doesn't look like it should be called with a calling context). `let total = 0` would make much more sense

Comment: It's not a great example honestly, there are plenty of reasons to use `this` but this isn't one of them.

Comment: FYI, `this` does not refer to the outer function. `this` is some unknown value that was passed in when `sum` is called. It's important to understand that `this` isn't referencing the function, it is just scoped within the outer function like any variable would be.

Comment: I think you are correct-- this is a contrived example in order to show how arrow functions solve issues around `this` in a simplified format.  This is _not_ a practical real world example-- generally, in my experience, the usage of arrow functions to solve `this` issues are most common/useful in the context of a `class`.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery can you show a proper one? I copied this in an article somewhere

Comment: Can you post the real example?

Answer (score 0):

Local variable make sense in above case. But **this** (lexical scope) using arrow function has wider use.

Now a days you uses framework for your project which has components and all. We have variable at component level and then that are bound to html.

```
class component {
  constructor() {
   this.data  = {};
  }
  // lets say you bring data and have to assign to above this.data
  getData() {

      somePromise.then((res) => {
        this.data = res // you can access parent. No this dra,a
      })
  }     

 }
```

But in case of normal function

```
  getData() {
      const self = this; // save parent this to local variable
      somePromise.then(function(res) {
           self.data = res // now you can set data as function'this is different here
      })
   }
```

There are other approach as well. You can bind your anonymous function with this using native bind function and then you can access valid **this** inside anonymous function.

So in real world, arrow function has solved this dilemma brilliantly.